# Blake's Seven timeline

Tags: timeline, blakes-7

I cannot find a good resource for a timeline, -- with dates in an in-Universe dating system -- for the back-story and plot of Blake's 7.

From what I can tell from tangential references, the B7 universe uses our current dating system and is set at various points towards the end of the current millennium. For example, the B7 wiki suggests that Star One was commissioned in 2760.

Has a good canonical timeline been developed? Failing that any clues to a broad-brush description of the calendar and approximate timings of important events would be appreciated.

For context, the purpose of this request is to attempt to keep various pieces of fiction reasonably canonical.

Comment: I've been a long time B7 fan and sadly I don't think there's one out there... only timelines that explain where the associated media (like audiodrama's and annuals come in). Sadly Terry Nation might have been the only one who could have answered this question =\